# Chaning SSL Certificate

Tags: batch-file, ssl, openssl, ca

### **What I have done?**

Genrared SSL Root Certificate and normal certificate and sign is using root crt and OpenSSL from batch code:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 1825 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem
```

### What is the issue?

Then I open signed server certificate it don't show chain that lead to Root certificate.
[image: Certificate Chain Image]

### For what result I am looking?

Fix/New openssl command or any other thing that would chain thoose certificate and can be done using batch script.

Solution should looks like this:

[image: this]

(But in certificate path in image 1 you cann't see the root one.)
ps: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YgaZIFn7mY) tutorial I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate was detected as self-signed and Root CA wasn't installed